# javapns Error handling in mac

Tags: java, web-services, apple-push-notifications, javapns

I have done APNS via PHP server side service. It worked perfectly. Now I try to do the same with java code. I found a package from the following URL:

https://code.google.com/p/javapns/downloads/list

When I try to run this code I get the following errors:

```
error: cannot find symbol
            pushManager.initializeConnection( HOST, PORT, certificate, passwd, SSLConnectionHelper.KEYSTORE_TYPE_PKCS12);

error: cannot find symbol
            Device client = pushManager.getDevice( "iPhone" );
            ^
  symbol:   class Device
  location: class APNS_TEST
```

Comment: have you imported all the necessary classes in your code ?

Comment: yeah but I still get this error

Comment: provide full code then only we can help @jayasabeen

Comment: I found this code from https://code.google.com/p/javapns/downloads/list

Comment: @Jayasabeen...yes thats ok , i want the code which you have written ?